# Weighted Averages from the world of GMAT..

Tags: average

I am really confused about how this question has been solved. I've given the question, author's approach and then mine. Can you help me figure out why/ why not I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Suraj

*Question*

A milkman has 20 L of milk. He mixes 5 L of water in 20 L of pure milk. If the cost of pure milk is $18/L, then the profit of the milkman, when he sells the **diluted** milk at cost price is:

A) 20%   B) 25%   C) 33.33%   D) 18%

*The Author's approach*

% Profit= 5/20=0.25=25%

*My approach*

The weighted percentage of milk in the new mixture=

{(1*20)+ (0*5)}/25

=0.8

=80% milk

% profit=

{(25)- (25*0.80)}/(25*0.80) where (25*0.80)= Actual price of diluted milk

=25%

Comment: Oh God. I apologize. I seem to have made a mistake in arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You made an arithmetic error when you calculated $\frac{1\cdot 20+0\cdot 5}{25}=\frac{20+0}{25}=\frac{4}{5}=0.8\neq 0.83$

Indeed, making the correction, you should arrive at:

$\frac{25-25\cdot 0.8}{25\cdot 0.8} = \frac{25-20}{20}=\frac{5}{20}=0.25$ as expected.